# How do we answer the question of "what is it"?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, definitions, explanation, introduction-to-philosophy

What is an electron? How do we answer such questions? If we try to explain it in more fundamental terms, we have to ask what is that and keeps going. So, my question is should we take things like electron, quarks, space, time, consciousness as undefineable quantities which just exist?

So electron is something that exists and has such and such properties. Same for other quantities. It's like how we define a set in math. We don't define it per se but give it lots of properties (axioms).

Comment: Physics: [The quantum theory of electron](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1928.0023).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeah, we have a good theory for subatomic particles better than the one provide by Dirac, i.e. QFT. This gives us many properties for it but doesn't answer the question of what it is. Ofcourse, physicists follow the ideology that the question "what is it" doesn't make sense and only properties matter. I'm asking if that's the best we can do.

Comment: In what way do you think we can achieve "better" knowledge: we do not perceive it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Well, we perceive a collection of subatomic particles (our brain/body). When I say he's my friend, I mean the consciousness in that body is my friend. So you're suggesting something similar for electron? It is it's consciousness (assuming panpsychism)?

Comment: Hi, this view of things inside things relates to Atomism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomism

Comment: I’d say this too big a quesion to answer as-is as realists and nonrealists will have wildly different answers. And if you think the conception of “is” is any better for mathematics, you’d be mistaken. What is answerable is what each discipline will say but that’s quite an order.

Comment: Perhaps we can start with an easier question. What is a bowling ball? Reminds me of the Feynman story about taking a philosophy class, and he was asked if an electron is an *essential object*. He responded by asking, "Is a brick an essential object?" He writes, "What I had intended to do was to find out whether they thought theoretical constructs were essential objects. The electron is a theory that we use; it is so useful in understanding the way nature works that we can almost call it real. I wanted to make the idea of a theory clear by analogy.  [continued ...]

Comment: [...] In the case of the brick, my next question was going to be, “What about the inside of the brick?”–and I would then point out that no one has ever seen the inside of a brick. Every time you break the brick, you only see the surface. That the brick has an inside is a simple theory which helps us understand things better. The theory of electrons is analogous. So I began by asking, “Is a brick an essential object?”" and then he reports that the class descended into confusion over whether a brick is an essential object.

Comment: See Leibniz's Law of indiscernable of identities which hopefully may have some insight and impact upon you...

Comment: Also see Spinoza's core philosophy. To the question of "What is?" he replies: "Substance, its attributes, and modes"...

Answer (score 6):

1.) Before answering a ‚What is?‘-question it may help to clarify:

> Which type of statement would I accept as a satisfying answer?

We are not familiar with objects like electrons, protons, positrons, photons, quarks etc. These entities belong to a domain where our senses do not have access to. We cannot define electrons by classifying them according to one of our familiar classfications from everyday experience.

2.) We observe physical phenomena which can be explained best by the hypothesis of entities with properties described by a corresponding theory:

- An electron/positron is an object which satisfies the Dirac equation
  and has charge -e/+e. That’s a good approximation, see Mauro’s
  link to Dirac's paper [The quantum theory of the electron](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1928.0023).
- A better approximation refers to Quantum Electrodynamics (QED). At least here, concepts like
  individuality loose their meaning and hinder any concrete
  visualisation of single objects. Possibly the 'naked' electron is a
  limit concept because electrons are always associated with a cloud of
  virtual particles. Hence it could be better to conceive an electron not as a an isolated entity but as a process.

3.) Answers like these are far away from Aristole’s approach to determine objects by giving their essence, not to mention his doctrine of the four causes.

4.) Summing up: 'Electron' is a technical term from a physical theory. Within the theory an electron is characterized by a set of properties. The theory makes predictions about some related, observable phenomena. In this sense the theory explains what an electron is.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a chair is also a theoretical object, whose existence we hypothesize on the basis of sense data. And the hypothesis could be wrong, if it is an illusion or hallucination of a chair. There is no division between "scientific" objects and "ordinary" ones; both are theorized on the basis of observations.

Comment: @causitive A scientific ontological commitment carries with it a superior epistemic endorsement. The division is the degree to which scientific methodologies are conducted to establish existence and justify and explain. To claim that an object endorsed by scientific practices is equivalent to the claims of a stone age community is a laughable claim.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to answer a why question, no matter how many intermediate logical steps are explained there may always arise a new why question. So generally we accept a logical consequence of one thing to another and even if we go deeper in examining the whys at some point we find a logical bond between two states in order to proceed forward.

For example if we dedicate a computer in finding all the digits of pi it would work forever calculating more and more digits. So, in fact we calculate so many digits as to how accurate we want to make a specific calculation.

In the same sense we stop asking when we have sufficent information to go on.

In this case if you really want to answer the question "what is it" you would go on forever until everything that has ever happened and thought of, is integrated back to a single entity (god) and because of this unity, every question would be meaningless!

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Well, three ways philosophers usually answer the question of 'what is it' are **names, definitions and [descriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description), and explanations** with the first being the briefest and the last being subject to a lifetime of study.

### Long Answer

The question of 'what is it' falls under the domain of [ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology). For thousands of years, philosophers have wrestled with the way to answer this question, but generally, most times when the question is asked, one is most interested in [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(philosophy)). It is the trivial case. What is it? A book. What is it? The tangent squared. What is it? I don't know what it's called; and generally we can tell the difference between things using [Leibniz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles). Of course, philosophical identity can get tricky, such as with both the [sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox) and [Ship of Theseus thought-experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).

But after moving beyond simple questions of identity and identifiers which was a topic of interest often explored with the terms [sense and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference), the next step is usually a brief description called a [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition). Of course, there are many types of definitions: ostensitive, intensional, extensional, circular, genus-species, precising, and so on. What is it? ~*Points to the flowers.*~ What is it? The class of all featherless bipbeds. What is it? The set of 24 dishes: 8 cups, 8 saucers, 8 bowls. What is it? The class of persons born on October 23rd, 1999 who currently resides in the boundaries of the city of New York with a height under 6' who owns a dog. Often times, the use of [sufficient and necessary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) can be used, but that sort of definition often leads to [loopholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loophole) due to the ambiguity which inheres in natural language. Another type of definition is the [prototype definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_theory). Descriptions are essentially detailed [narration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narration) that go above and beyond the succinctness of a definition.

Lastly, (and my favorite, much to the chagrin of my wife) one has  [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanation) which many people characterize with different methodologies and definitions. For instance, there is theological explanation, explanatory myths, lay-person explanations, [metaphysical explanation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysical-explanation/) and [scientific explanation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-explanation/). And naturally, among each category, one finds various methodologies. See [Which Question Is Right for Functional Analysis? (PhilSE)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90954/which-question-is-right-for-functional-analysis) for a brief discussion of one form of scientific explanation.

> So, my question is should we take things like electron, quarks, space, time, consciousness as undefinable quantities which just exist?

Well, that depends on your metaphysical preferences. Kant defined space and time as forms that concepts take that inhere to the property of the mind. A scientist will tell you an electron fundamentally exists within a standard model or system of particles. It's up to you to decide what requires explanation and description and which is [brute fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_fact). What you should do with philosophy, in fact, is a [normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativity) question studied in [metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy).